Valid children types for Terminal screen in WhatsApp Flows
I'm creating a WhatsApp Flow that needs to route to certain screens based on the user's choices that they make in the radio button question. I received an error stating that a Terminal screen is required, which I then added to the flow. But I am struggling to find a valid children type that will work on this Terminal screen as I receive errors for the types that I am trying to use saying that they are all invalid. For instance, in the below code snippet I get an error on "Text" saying that it's an invalid type.
{
      "id": "TERMINAL",
      "title": "Terminal Screen",
      "data": {},
      "terminal": true,
      "layout": {
        "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "Form",
            "name": "end_path",
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "Text",
                "label": "Thank you.",
                "name": "thank_you_message"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

I tried looking online for valid types and could not find anything related to Terminal Screens. I tried "Label" "Output" "Notification" "Info" and "Alert" but none of these worked. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
